# Unable to add Minim-Android library in Android Studio with jitpack

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, minim, jitpack

I am trying to add to my build.gradle file in Android Studio the following dependency:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1883

I followed the intstructions found in package tab of this page, but when I tried to build the project I got the following message:

> Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.github.DASAR:Minim-Android:a73b596916

Anyone can help me?

I also tried to download the project code and import it in Android Studio as a module, but it wasn't recognized as a library from the wizard.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think that you can't use it with jitpack because the library hasn't a build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

You can download relative API in your AS SDK Manager, then add it in build.gradle.  After that, check out the compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion are same with  appcompat. My build.gradle is:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'

}
```

my sdk is 19

Comment: This does not relate to what I asked

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to fork the project and add a Gradle build file. Then use JitPack to build the fork. 
Note that the project has dependencies in a libs/ folder so these would need to be converted to dependencies in Gradle.